# Generating Random Numbers in C# , declaring seed and min interval and max interval

Tags: c#

i have defined a method like this:

```
private String getRadndomNumber(int min, int max) {
    Random rnd = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
    return Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(min,max));
}
```

I am defining both seed and min,max interval , I wanted to know whether the SEED value is of any help here or not ?

tnx :)

Comment: Consider renaming the method ;)

Comment: It helps but here it doesn't work. Granularity of DateTime.Now may be even more than 20 milliseconds and if you call that function twice in a very short time (note...you applied a mask too so you'll increase the interval!) you'll get the same result multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seed helps you generate a random number, it's the base number used for their random algorithm. Using the same seed each time could end up with a predictable set of "random" numbers coming out in sequence.

From the MS documentation:

> "If your application requires different random number sequences,
>   invoke this constructor repeatedly with different seed values. One way
>   to produce a unique seed value is to make it time-dependent. For
>   example, derive the seed value from the system clock. However, the
>   system clock might not have sufficient resolution to provide different
>   invocations of this constructor with a different seed value."

The default constructor uses the system clock as seed but multiple instances created in the same tick could cause predictable numbers between the generators.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the seed value is of any help depends on what you're trying to do!

You're using `DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0xFFFF` as the seed, which means that *(i)* you're basing the seed on the current time, and *(ii)* you're limiting that seed to values between 0 and 65535. In general, neither of these are a particularly good idea. The granularity of the system clock is about 15ms (iirc), so any calls to your method within the same 15ms "segment" will result in the same seed being used.

If you don't pass an explicit seed to the `Random` constructor then it effectively uses `Environment.TickCount & 0x7FFFFFFF` as the seed. So it will still be based on the current time, but it will have a much wider range than your custom seed: 0 to 2147483647.

From the [documentation for the `Random(Int32)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx)...

> Providing an identical seed value to different `Random` objects causes
>   each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers.

From the [documentation for the `Random()` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx)...

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has
>   finite resolution. As a result, different `Random` objects that are
>   created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will
>   have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce
>   identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using
>   a single `Random` object to generate all random numbers.